# How to force Junit report in Jenkins pipline?

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am trying to display junit test report from a downstream job - at an upstream job. Using Jenkins declerative pipeline.

However, I keep getting:

> Error when executing always post condition:
>
> hudson.AbortException: Test reports were found but none of them are
>   new. Did leafNodes run?

I have Archived the report at the downstream job.
Copied the build artifacts (using copyArtifact) into a directory in the current (upstream) job workspace.
Called junit on the copied report.
Still getting this error.

Attempted this both at a stage in the pipeline and at 'post'.

```
post{
    always{
        dir ('archive') {
            deleteDir()
            copyArtifacts(projectName: 'build_job', selector: specific(BUILD_NUM), fingerprintArtifacts: true)
            junit testResults: "**/*.xml", allowEmptyResults: true
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to be able to see tests from the downstream job, appear in the TestResults section in the build summary.

Comment: It is not really clear what your question is for me. Yes, you should be able to see the report imo.

Comment: thank you. I have edited the post to be clearer.
I am trying to display downstream junit report at the upstream job that called it.
but keep getting `Test reports were found but none of them are new` exception

Comment: are you running junit reports twice by any chance?

Comment: I am. 
First for the downstream job, and then again for the upstream job (but there is an archive-copyArtifact step in between)